# How to test methods imported from other components or JS file

Tags: vuejs2, jestjs, vue-test-utils

I don´t have much experience with unit testing.
What is the proper way to test a method imported from a JS file or from another component?

This is a sample component I created a localSum just to use on the test.

```js
<template>
    <div class="fixed-center text-center text-h2">
        <p>{{ getSum }}</p>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import { sum } from './testComponent.js';

export default {
    name: 'TestComponent',
    data() {
        return {
            a: 10,
            b: 20
        }
    },
    computed: {
        getSum() {
            return sum(this.a, this.b);
        }
    },
    methods: {
        localSum(a, b) {
            return a + b;
        }
    }
};
</script>
```

The JS file:

```js
export function sum(a, b) {
    return a + b;
}
```

This is the test, maybe I should not be using `wrapper.vm` to access the method?
One note: On the real component I don't want to test the method directly, which is why I did not import `sum` from the JS file.

```js
import { mount } from '@vue/test-utils';
import TestComponent from '@components/TestComponent.vue';

describe('Testing component', () => { 
    test('Testing local method', () => { 
        const wrapper = mount(TestComponent);

        expect(wrapper.vm.localSum(10, 20)).toBe(30);
    });

    test('Testing method from js file', () => { 
        const wrapper = mount(TestComponent);

        expect(wrapper.vm.getSum(10, 20)).toBe(30);
    });
});
```

Test result:

```
Testing component
    ✓ Testing local method (6 ms)
    ✕ Testing method from js file (2 ms)

  ● Testing component › Testing method from js file

    TypeError: wrapper.vm.getSum is not a function
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example `getSum()` is a computed property that doesn't take any argument.
Therefore to test it you probably just need to do:

```
expect(wrapper.vm.getSum).toBe(30);
```

instead of:

```
expect(wrapper.vm.getSum(10, 20)).toBe(30);
```